# A growing a panel does not end at the end of the JFrame - FormLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jgoodies

I have the below code, where I have a JPanel that needs to occupy all the space of the JFrame but stop when the frame completes. When using the Form Layout it does not. Please see the below code

```
import com.jgoodies.forms.debug.FormDebugPanel;
import com.jgoodies.forms.layout.FormLayout;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final JFrame frame=new JFrame();
                JPanel panel=new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                FormDebugPanel comp = new FormDebugPanel(
                        new FormLayout("10dlu,fill:pref:grow,10dlu","10dlu,fill:pref:grow,10dlu"));
                panel.add(comp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.setContentPane(panel);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

This results in the diagram below. The border on the right and the bottom does not show, since it looks like the panel continues to grow beyond the parent container's boundary. Is there something that I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean *"when the frame completes"*?

Comment: may i know why you are using `FormDebugPanel comp = new FormDebugPanel` ?

Comment: by frame completes I mean, the Jpanel should grow more than the boundaries of its parent container..I am using a FormDebugPanel to demonstrate that the red borders are not drawn on the right most and bottom most column and row. Its an SSCCE that shows the issue I am facing elsewhere in my code

Comment: It's not an sscce if you don't have jgoodies

Comment: Have you tried a simple `frame.pack()`?... Which you should have already done, by the way

Comment: It doesn't work even after adding the pack().

Answer (score 0):

You must either set a preferred size on the frame first or change the grow and fill.
pack() only works if you are packing after formdebugpanel loaded its components.